# Is this possible in SQL?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a table containing some data which needs to be displayed in a certain format on screen.

The table structures are as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobSheet](
    [JobSheetID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SheetNumber] [bigint] NULL,
    [JobSheetDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ContractID] [bigint] NULL,
    [ContractCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContractTitle] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ProjectID] [bigint] NULL,
    [ProjectCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProjectTitle] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [JobID] [bigint] NULL,
    [JobCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [JobTitle] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [SageDatabaseID] [bigint] NULL,
    [SageDatabaseName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EnteredByID] [bigint] NULL,
    [EnteredByUsername] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DocumentStatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NULL,
    [Reference] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedUser] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SentToSage] [bit] NULL,
    [UpdateStatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_JobSheet] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JobSheetID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobSheetLine](
    [JobSheetLineID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [JobSheetID] [bigint] NULL,
    [LineType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TSHumanResourceID] [bigint] NULL,
    [SageDatabaseID] [bigint] NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Initial] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [TimeOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [TimeOff] [datetime] NULL,
    [Deleted] [bit] NULL,
    [B1] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [B15] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [B2] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [HB] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [S1] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [S15] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [S2] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [HS] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [O1] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [T] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [TS] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [TT] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [TP] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [OT] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [OS] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [D] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [POA] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [PT1] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [PT2] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [CustomCostRate1] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [CustomCostRate1ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [CustomCostRate2] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [CustomCostRate2ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [CustomCostRate3] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [CustomCostRate3ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [CustomCostRate4] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [CustomCostRate4ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [CustomCostRate5] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [CustomCostRate5ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [CustomCostRate6] [decimal](18, 5) NULL,
    [CustomCostRate6ID] [bigint] NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [UpdatedUser] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RejectReason] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [CurrentStepApprovalCount] [bigint] NULL,
    [CustomRouteID] [bigint] NULL,
    [CustomRoute] [bit] NULL,
    [CurrentStep] [bigint] NULL,
    [WaitingForType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [WaitingForID] [bigint] NULL,
    [RequestedByID] [bigint] NULL,
    [LineStatus] [varchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_JobSheetLine] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JobSheetLineID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The data is entered on a screen like this which may show the format of the JobSheetLineTable better:
[image]

The required format I need to get the data out is like the screenshot below:
[image]

The Data needs to be filtered by employee (RequestedByID in the JobSheetLine table)
and each unique, Contract and Project, and Cost Rate (the cost rates run from B1, B15, B2 etc all the way to CustomCostRate6).

The total number of hours for each cost rate needs to be per day.

I have got as far as the query below until I relized this is not going to work. I think the problem is caused due to the cost rates being Columns in the JobSheetLine table, but the required output has the cost rate as a single column and rates and values appear on the rows.

I looked into using the PIVOT keyword in SQL but I couldn't work out what I was doing with it.

Here is the query I have come up with so far (which wont work)

```
DECLARE @Deleted AS BIT
DECLARE @RequestedByID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @WeekStartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WeekEndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WaitingForUserID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @WaitingForUserTypeID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @WaitingForTypeUser AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @WaitingForTypeUserType AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @Deleted = 0
SET @RequestedByID = 2
SET @WeekStartDate = '2011/05/23 00:00'
SET @WeekEndDate = '2011/05/29 00:00'


SELECT 
[JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
[JobSheet].[ContractID],
[JobSheet].[ContractCode],
[JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
[JobSheet].[ProjectID],
[JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
[JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
[JobSheet].[JobID],
[JobSheet].[JobCode],
[JobSheet].[JobTitle],
[JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[B1]),0) AS B1,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[B15]),0) AS B15,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[B2]),0) AS B2,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[HB]),0) AS HB,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[S1]),0) AS S1,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[S15]),0) AS S15,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[S2]),0) AS S2,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[HS]),0) AS HS,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[O1]),0) AS O1,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[T]),0) AS T,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[TS]),0) AS TS,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[TT]),0) AS TT,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[TP]),0) AS TP,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[OT]),0) AS OT,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[OS]),0) AS OS,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[D]),0) AS D,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[POA]),0) AS POA,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[PT1]),0) AS PT1,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[PT2]),0) AS PT2,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate1]),0) AS CustomCostRate1,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate2]),0) AS CustomCostRate2,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate3]),0) AS CustomCostRate3,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate4]),0) AS CustomCostRate4,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate5]),0) AS CustomCostRate5,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate6]),0) AS CustomCostRate6,
ISNULL(SUM([JobSheetLine].[B1] + 
           [JobSheetLine].[B15] +
           [JobSheetLine].[B2] +
           [JobSheetLine].[HB] +
           [JobSheetLine].[S1] +
           [JobSheetLine].[S15] +
           [JobSheetLine].[S2] +
           [JobSheetLine].[HS] +
           [JobSheetLine].[O1] +
           [JobSheetLine].[T] +
           [JobSheetLine].[TS] +
           [JobSheetLine].[TT] +
           [JobSheetLine].[TP] +
           [JobSheetLine].[OT] +
           [JobSheetLine].[OS] +
           [JobSheetLine].[D] +
           [JobSheetLine].[POA] +
           [JobSheetLine].[PT1] +
           [JobSheetLine].[PT2] +
           [JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate1] +
           [JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate2] +
           [JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate3] +
           [JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate4] +
           [JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate5] +
           [JobSheetLine].[CustomCostRate6]),0) AS TotalHours



FROM [JobSheet]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLine]
ON  [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetID]=[JobSheet].[JobSheetID]

WHERE 
    [JobSheet].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] >= @WeekStartDate
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] <= @WeekEndDate
AND [JobSheetLine].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheetLine].[RequestedByID]=@RequestedByID

GROUP BY 
    [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
    [JobSheet].[ContractID],
    [JobSheet].[ContractCode],
    [JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectID],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
    [JobSheet].[JobID],
    [JobSheet].[JobCode],
    [JobSheet].[JobTitle],
    [JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID]
```

Is it possible to achieve the output I want with the structure of the data as it is at the moment? I would rather do all the calculation in SQL as its faster but I can do some of the calculation in C# as this is an asp.net project.

Comment: None of your columns from the "desired output" exist in the posted schema (besides I am guessing ProjectId = Project)?

Comment: I feel sorry for whomever gets listed in your report. Who can survive on £7.51 /h ? :-)

Comment: @JNK - The costt Rates  i mentioned (B1, b15, b2 etc) should be displayed as rows in the Pay Code column of the desired output (if you look at the screenshot you can actually see the cost rates) This is all I have to work with as well

Comment: There is no way to hand this problem to the database designer who failed to normalize the ´JobSheetLine table´? The miserable design of that table is the root cause of your querying problems. Complex calculations and workarounds will frequently be necessary when dealing with data originating from this table

Comment: @Simen  S - It may be possible to normalise the table, what would you suggest? abstract the Cost Rate values to another table so there is only one cost rate code and value per line?

Comment: @WraithNath: Yes, I would have liked to have a table which only has *one* column where you store *hours*, and where you have foreign keys to cost rate, job line etc. Your current JobSheetLine implementation is going ot cause trouble once someone decides to add/delete or change a cost rate. You will, however, still have to resolve some interdependencies between the sum of the values in your new table and the times in your timeOn/timeOff columns.

Comment: @Simen S - thanks for your response, Ill have a look into how much working changing the table would be, I suspect there will have to be a rewrite of the entry page unless the properties of the JobSheetLine class can be changed to look up from another table. Thanks

Comment: If your application is written to use stored procedures to do its get and set operations then it should be a fairly simple (although maybe tedious) change, which should only involve some T-SQL coding.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you mean when you say the query won't work. Perhaps you should add a couple of inserts into your tables and explain what's wrong with the output

Comment: @Simen S - The table has now been normalised and the query is working as expected, I have a new problem now but ill post that seperately if I cant work it out. if you want to post your normalise the table answer as an answer, ill mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in my comment to the original question, I belive normalization is a good long-term solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Answer to this question was suggested by Simen S. The Tables needed to be normalised in to the format below:

[image]