# Help with a SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question on a SQL query and im wondering where to start. Thoughts so far include creating a table in memory with a range of dates, and joining on to it to get the sum of hours entered for a particular day.

Just to give an idea of the background of this question here is a little information.

The database is structured like so:
[image]

The result im trying to achieve with the query im currently writing needs to look like this:
[image]

The Query I have written so far:

```
DECLARE @Deleted AS BIT
DECLARE @WeekStartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WeekEndDate AS DATETIME

SET @Deleted = 0
SET @WeekStartDate = '2011/05/01 00:00'
SET @WeekEndDate = '2011/05/07 00:00'

SELECT 
[JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
[JobSheet].[ContractID],
[JobSheet].[ContractCode],
[JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
[JobSheet].[ProjectID],
[JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
[JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
[JobSheet].[JobID],
[JobSheet].[JobCode],
[JobSheet].[JobTitle],
[JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
[JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode],
SUM([JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]) AS TotalCostRateHours,
'???' AS 'Mon',
'???' AS 'Tue',
'???' AS 'Wed',
'???' AS 'Thu',
'???' AS 'Fri',
'???' AS 'Sat',
'???' AS 'Sun'

FROM [JobSheet]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLine]
ON  [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetID]
=   [JobSheet].[JobSheetID]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLineHours]
ON  [JobSheetLineHours].[JobSheetLineID]
=   [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetLineID]

WHERE 
    [JobSheet].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] >= @WeekStartDate
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] <= @WeekEndDate
AND [JobSheetLine].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheetLineHours].[Deleted]=@Deleted

GROUP BY 
    [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
    [JobSheet].[ContractID],
    [JobSheet].[ContractCode],
    [JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectID],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
    [JobSheet].[JobID],
    [JobSheet].[JobCode],
    [JobSheet].[JobTitle],
    [JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
    [JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode]
```

And this outputs the result set below:
[image]

As you can see the result set is almost there, I just need to total the number of hours worked on that particular day, grouping on ContractID, JobID, ProjectID, CostRateCode so I can get the number of hours for each cost rate on each unique project.

Is this possible with the current table design? or by using a temporary calendar table for the dates between the two passed in to the query?

EDIT:
Updated Query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Set the first day of week to monday
GO

DECLARE @Deleted AS BIT
DECLARE @RequestedByID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @WeekStartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WeekEndDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WaitingForUserID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @WaitingForUserTypeID AS BIGINT
DECLARE @WaitingForTypeUser AS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @WaitingForTypeUserType AS VARCHAR(50)

SET @Deleted = 0
SET @WeekStartDate = '2009/05/01 00:00'
SET @WeekEndDate = '2012/05/07 00:00'

SELECT 
[JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
[JobSheet].[ContractID],
[JobSheet].[ContractCode],
[JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
[JobSheet].[ProjectID],
[JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
[JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
[JobSheet].[JobID],
[JobSheet].[JobCode],
[JobSheet].[JobTitle],
[JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
[JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode],
SUM([JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]) AS TotalCostRateHours,
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 1 
THEN SUM(JobSheetLineHours.Hours )
END 
AS MON,
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 2 
THEN SUM(JobSheetLineHours.Hours )
END 
AS TUE, 
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 3 
THEN SUM(JobSheetLineHours.Hours )
END 
AS WED,
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 4 
THEN SUM(JobSheetLineHours.Hours )
END 
AS THU,
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 5 
THEN SUM(JobSheetLineHours.Hours )
END 
AS FRI,
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 6 
THEN SUM(JobSheetLineHours.Hours )
END 
AS SAT,
CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 7 
THEN SUM(JobSheetLineHours.Hours )
END 
AS SUN

FROM [JobSheet]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLine]
ON  [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetID]
=   [JobSheet].[JobSheetID]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLineHours]
ON  [JobSheetLineHours].[JobSheetLineID]
=   [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetLineID]

WHERE 
    [JobSheet].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] >= @WeekStartDate
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] <= @WeekEndDate
AND [JobSheetLine].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheetLineHours].[Deleted]=@Deleted

GROUP BY 
    [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
    [JobSheet].[ContractID],
    [JobSheet].[ContractCode],
    [JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectID],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
    [JobSheet].[JobID],
    [JobSheet].[JobCode],
    [JobSheet].[JobTitle],
    [JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
    [JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode],
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
    WHEN 1 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 2 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END, 
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 3 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 4 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 5 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 6 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 7 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END
```

Updated Result Set:
[image]

What I'm trying to do now is remove the JobSheetDate from the result set so the Total hours for each day are not all on seperate rows eg. The values for the same contract, project etc are put in the same row, but in the Mon, Tues, Wed etc column, rather than on multiple rows with the hours for one day populated, and the rest of the days null (see screenshot)

---

EDIT 2:
Updated Query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Set the first day of week to monday
GO

DECLARE @Deleted AS BIT
DECLARE @WeekStartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WeekEndDate AS DATETIME

SET @Deleted = 0
SET @WeekStartDate = '2009/05/01 00:00'
SET @WeekEndDate = '2012/05/07 00:00'

SELECT 
--[JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
[JobSheet].[ContractID],
[JobSheet].[ContractCode],
[JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
[JobSheet].[ProjectID],
[JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
[JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
[JobSheet].[JobID],
[JobSheet].[JobCode],
[JobSheet].[JobTitle],
[JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
[JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode],
SUM([JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]) AS TotalCostRateHours,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 1 
THEN JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END )
AS MON,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 2 
THEN JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END )
AS TUE, 
SUM(CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 3 
THEN JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END)
AS WED,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 4 
THEN JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END) 
AS THU,
SUM(CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 5 
THEN JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END )
AS FRI,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 6 
THEN JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END )
AS SAT,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
WHEN 7 
THEN JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END )
AS SUN

FROM [JobSheet]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLine]
ON  [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetID]
=   [JobSheet].[JobSheetID]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLineHours]
ON  [JobSheetLineHours].[JobSheetLineID]
=   [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetLineID]

WHERE 
    [JobSheet].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] >= @WeekStartDate
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] <= @WeekEndDate
AND [JobSheetLine].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheetLineHours].[Deleted]=@Deleted

GROUP BY 
    --[JobSheet].[JobSheetDate],
    [JobSheet].[ContractID],
    [JobSheet].[ContractCode],
    [JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectID],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
    [JobSheet].[JobID],
    [JobSheet].[JobCode],
    [JobSheet].[JobTitle],
    [JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
    [JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode],
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) 
    WHEN 1 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 2 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END, 
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 3 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 4 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 5 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 6 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END,
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) WHEN 7 
    THEN     JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
    END
```

Results:
[image]

---

FINAL Update with finished Query:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Set the first day of week to monday
GO

DECLARE @Deleted AS BIT
DECLARE @WeekStartDate AS DATETIME
DECLARE @WeekEndDate AS DATETIME

SET @Deleted = 0
SET @WeekStartDate = '2009/05/01 00:00'
SET @WeekEndDate = '2012/05/07 00:00'

SELECT 
[JobSheet].[ContractID],
[JobSheet].[ContractCode],
[JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
[JobSheet].[ProjectID],
[JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
[JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
[JobSheet].[JobID],
[JobSheet].[JobCode],
[JobSheet].[JobTitle],
[JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
[JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode],
SUM([JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]) AS TotalCostRateHours,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate]) -- Get Total Value for Monday
     WHEN 1 
     THEN [JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]
     END )
AS MON,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate]) -- Get Total Value for Tuesday
     WHEN 2 
     THEN [JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]
     END )
AS TUE, 
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate]) -- Get Total Value for Wednesday
     WHEN 3 
     THEN [JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]
     END )
AS WED,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate]) -- Get Total Value for Thursday
     WHEN 4 
     THEN [JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]
     END ) 
AS THU,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate]) -- Get Total Value for Friday
     WHEN 5 
     THEN [JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]
     END )
AS FRI,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate]) -- Get Total Value for Saturday
     WHEN 6 
     THEN [JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]
     END )
AS SAT,
SUM( CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate]) -- Get Total Value for Sunday
     WHEN 7 
     THEN [JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]
     END )
AS SUN

FROM [JobSheet]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLine]
ON  [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetID]
=   [JobSheet].[JobSheetID]

INNER JOIN [JobSheetLineHours]
ON  [JobSheetLineHours].[JobSheetLineID]
=   [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetLineID]

WHERE 
    [JobSheet].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] >= @WeekStartDate
AND [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] <= @WeekEndDate
AND [JobSheetLine].[Deleted]=@Deleted
AND [JobSheetLineHours].[Deleted]=@Deleted

GROUP BY 
    [JobSheet].[ContractID],
    [JobSheet].[ContractCode],
    [JobSheet].[ContractTitle],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectID],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectCode],
    [JobSheet].[ProjectTitle],
    [JobSheet].[JobID],
    [JobSheet].[JobCode],
    [JobSheet].[JobTitle],
    [JobSheet].[SageDatabaseID],
    [JobSheetLineHours].[CostRateCode]
```

Comment: FYI, related but **not a dupe:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200942/is-this-possible-in-sql

Comment: How are you getting to know about the values for Mo, Tu, We  Th, FR and Is total = Mo + Tu + We + Th + FR; How are you calculating the gross pay ?

Comment: @SQL - The Values for Mo, Tu, We Etc is the part im now trying to work out. Essentially the value in hours is stored in the JobSheetLineHours table, And the Date for the Job Sheet is stored in the JobSheet table. Eac Jobsheet entered if for a single date. The gross pay will be stored in the JobSheetLineHours table after i have got the total hours for the days sorted. each row of the results will be stored in a .net class, so I was going to add a couple of properties to the class to return the gross pay. If it helps you can assume the Pay Rate will be in the JobSheetLineHours table

Comment: @JNK - This is a follow on from the other question, The other question is answered, I was just asking the person who helped last time if they wanted to post as an aswer rather than a comment before I answer it myself. Had take the Hours and cost rates out into this JobSheetLineHours table

Comment: @Wraith - Yep I know it's different.  I started to mark it as a dupe because I remembered the first one, but I re-read both and realized they are distinct.  I added the comment to keep others from doing the same.

Comment: can you add the screen shot when you say "What I'm trying to do now is remove the JobSheetDate from the result set so the Total hours for each day are not all on seperate rows eg. The values for the same contract, project etc are put in the same row, but in the Mon, Tues, Wed etc column, rather than on multiple rows with the hours for one day populated, and the rest of the days null (see screenshot)"

Comment: @SQL - is the very last screenshot labeled Updated Result Set: If you can see the null values to the right of it, you can see about half the values are in the thurs column, and half in the fri column. Although the projects and contracts are the same for these transactions they are being split like this, whereas I was hopeing only the records that have a value in the thurs column would be visible, and the hours from the fri column of the other records, would be in the fri column of the records with a value in the thurs column. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: What I have understood so far is that, You want select statement that will show the result for weekly data for the same project / contract / Cost Rate code. In case the project and contract is same and the week is different then it will come up in different row. In this way the date column should be excluded. Right?

Comment: @SQL - yes, I think that is correct. Any records that have the same contract, project, job and Cost rate code should appear on the same row if the JobSheetDate is between the date range of the week.  If the contract or Cost Rate code is different then it should appear on a new row. It should not be possible to get dates outside of the week as the range is passed into the query.

Comment: One more thing please confirm that, the first two rows in the last screen shot, should be merged into one row which will have total = 3 , so that wed and thr will have values in one row only.

Comment: @SQL - Thats correct, becuase the CostRateCode is the same on the first two rows the total hours should be merged to the same row, and The total would be 3 as you suggest. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look into it using the sample table scheme. Hope it will help you. Never underwent such situation. Glad to learn something new today. Thanks for the Post **WraithNath**

```
create table #temp
(
    projectId int,
    ContractID int,
    CostRateCode varchar(10),
    JobSheetDate datetime,
    Hours Int   
)
```

I inserted few records like below

```
Insert into #temp(projectId, ContractID, CostRateCode, JobSheetDate, Hours)
Values(1, 1, 'A', '2011-06-02 22:00:35.337', 1)

Insert into #temp(projectId, ContractID, CostRateCode, JobSheetDate, Hours)
Values(1, 1, 'A', '2011-06-01 22:00:35.337', 2)

Insert into #temp(projectId, ContractID, CostRateCode, JobSheetDate, Hours)
Values(1, 1, 'A', '2011-05-31 22:00:35.337', 3)

Insert into #temp(projectId, ContractID, CostRateCode, JobSheetDate, Hours)
Values(1, 1, 'A', '2011-06-03 22:00:35.337', 6)

Insert into #temp(projectId, ContractID, CostRateCode, JobSheetDate, Hours)
Values(1, 1, 'A', '2011-05-30 22:00:35.337', 5)

Insert into #temp(projectId, ContractID, CostRateCode, JobSheetDate, Hours)
Values(1, 2, 'B', '2011-05-31 22:00:35.337', 4)

Insert into #temp(projectId, ContractID, CostRateCode, JobSheetDate, Hours)
Values(1, 2, 'B', '2011-06-01 22:00:35.337', 7)
```

Following is the situation after insertion

[image]

Finally the select statement

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

Select projectId ,ContractID ,CostRateCode,Sum(Hours) Total,
SUM(Case When DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheetDate) = 1 Then Hours Else 0 End) as 'Mon',
SUM(Case When DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheetDate) = 2 Then Hours Else 0 End) as 'Tue',
SUM(Case When DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheetDate) = 3 Then Hours Else 0 End) as 'Wed',
SUM(Case When DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheetDate) = 4 Then Hours Else 0 End) as 'Thu',
SUM(Case When DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheetDate) = 5 Then Hours Else 0 End) as 'Fri',
SUM(Case When DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheetDate) = 6 Then Hours Else 0 End) as 'Sat',
SUM(Case When DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheetDate) = 7 Then Hours Else 0 End) as 'Sun'
From #temp
Group By projectId ,ContractID ,CostRateCode

Drop table #temp
```

ResultSet

[image]

Comment: I have just tested you query and I am unbelievably happy to say it works perfectly! I think the problem I had was caused by having the Case statements in the group by clause as well as the select statement, after removing them from the group by clause its all working! +1 for the answer, Re-reading conrads answer I can see I should not have had the select statements in the group by cause but your fully query has cleared that up for me. Ill up vote All of your responses, but Ill mark Conrads as the answer as I couldnt not have got this working without his DateFirst suggestion too :)

Answer (score 7):

If I understand correctly you'll need to add this to your `SELECT`

**EDIT** Since you want sums you'll need to ADD SUMs around the case

```
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) = 1 THEN 
    JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END) AS MON,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) = 2 THEN 
    JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END) AS TUE, 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) = 3 THEN 
    JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END) AS WED,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) = 4 THEN 
    JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END) AS THU,
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, JobSheet.JobSheetDate) = 5 THEN 
    JobSheetLineHours.Hours 
END) AS FRI,
```

You'll also need to *remove* any [JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` to get the days all on one line

As noted in the comments this depends on how [SET DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) is set

Also it should be noted that whenever you have a `SUM(CASE` there's definitely a `PIVOT` alternative

Comment: @Conrad - Hi Conrad, thanks for your suggestion, I think I have it very nearly working. It took me a while to get it working, I had to replace the '=' signs with 'WHEN' statements as it didnt like it. I have updated my example with my complete query but there are a couple of problems. 1. The values are going into the wrong day. eg, 2011.06.16 is going into Friday Value when in fact its a thurs, is this a SQL setting for what day a week starts on? 2. Having the Job sheet date in the select statement causing more rows to be added with nulls for the other days (see screenshot)

Comment: ps. I also added SUM for the hours in the select statement as it was not totaling them

Comment: Doh I can't believe I forgot the `WHEN`'s. And yes its the [`SET DATEFIRST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) that affects this

Comment: @Conrad, thanks, I have added the DateFirst statement, didnt know about that one! Do you have any ideas on removing the GroupBy for the JobSheet Date so the total hours for each day are on a single line?

Comment: @Conrad - ah thanks, blind! I had the Sum statments inside the case, rather than outside so I have rectifed that. It has had an effect on the results, but there are not on the same line as yet, the do seem to be in a different order though!, im not sure if you can see what i mean in the new results screenshot? - is it something to do with the case's in the group by? it seems to be duplicating the CostRateCodes

Comment: Hi Conrad, I think Monday should have 2 value and Tue should have 3 like wise for other days. Isn't that ?

Comment: I have verified in my query window . Ran this statement select DATEPART(WEEKDAY, getdate()) and gave the result = 5. It is thursday today IST

Comment: @SQL - I had to use SET DATEFIRST to change the first day of the week to monday. I think you can use SELECT @@DATEFIRST to see what it is currently set to.

Comment: @SQL as noted it depends on what the value of `@@DATEFIRST` is. If you execute `SET DATEFIRST 1` you'll get 4

Comment: @Conrad - I'm going to pick this up again in the morning, I just need to get the values for the same Contracts, projects, jobs and Cost Rates codes on one line, currently the results are splitting on multiple rows ( the Cost Rate Code is appearing twice for the same contract, project and job, not sure if you can make it out in the latest result set screen shot). Your current and any further assistance is greatly appreciated! +1's for all you help so far.

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly acceptable (and often optimal) to create a concrete calendar table of days.

The table would be small and light, you could `JOIN` to it easily and group by any date combo you wanted. You could add a column to denote work-days versus off-days too if you like.

Otherwise it is awkward to get "zero hour" days because you're asking for an aggregation from data which doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for your response, Ill try a dynamic calendar table as well as Conrads suggestion. I do have a script to generate a calendar already as well this this bit I can take care of :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery where you have the question marks for the days, one subquery for each day of the week; the date of the day is calculated from dates passed in.  Monday's would be:

```
( SELECT SUM([JobSheetLineHours].[Hours]) 
  FROM [JobSheet]              
  INNER JOIN [JobSheetLine] ON [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetID] = 
    [JobSheet].[JobSheetID]
  INNER JOIN [JobSheetLineHours] ON [JobSheetLineHours].[JobSheetLineID] =   
    [JobSheetLine].[JobSheetLineID]
  WHERE[JobSheet].[JobSheetDate] = @WeekStartDate + 1 AND
   [JobSheet].[Deleted]=@Deleted AND 
   [JobSheetLine].[Deleted]=@Deleted AND 
   [JobSheetLineHours].[Deleted]=@Deleted )
```

For Tuesday you would add 2, etc.

*NOTE*: This will only work if @WeekStartDate is indeed a Sunday, though it seems that you are already assuming such.